# How to calculate increments by hierarchical categories python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, increment, pandas-groupby

Suppose that you have a DataFrame as the following:

```
     -Fruit-     -Shop-      -Total-   -Year-
 0    Apple      Maximo        100      2016
 1    Apple      John          200      2016
 2   Banana      John          400      2016
 3    Apple      Maximo         50      2017
 4    Apple      Maximo        100      2017
 5   Banana      John          300      2017
```

Then, you would like to calculate the increment between years by each combination of categories, saving it as a new column in a groupedby-DataFrame:

```
     -Fruit-    -Fruit-Increment-     -Shop-     -Shop-Increment-
 0    Apple         -50%              Maximo           50%   
 1    Apple         -50%              John            -100%   
 2   Banana         -25%              John            -25%
```

Explanation: The general increment 2016-2017 in sales of *Apple* was (Pseudocode-like example):

```
(Apple_2017_summed_values-Apple_2016_summed_values)/Apple_2016_summed_values
```

Which is the following operation with actual values:

```
(150-300)/300=-50%
```

However, I would also like to know how well did that fruit performed in each shop. In *Maximo*, the *Apple* Sales' increment is (150-100)/100=50% (And so on).

*Bonus 1:* include in the possible code a way to put a NaN if the value of 2016 was 0 and there was a value in 2017 (not possible to calculate an increment)

*Bonus 2:* Take into account the optimal way to solve this (I would like to implement it in a big DataFrame, where columns would be almost all categories)

**Please**, notify me if I'm unclear about what I want to achieve in order to correct the question. Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand your logic, how you get output from input data. Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael Already modify it, I would be glad if you can help me :(